# how to use getparam with bindparam the correct way

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I keep getting this error message.

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I am trying to place the variables in an array. but i keep getting the error, is there any stmt i should use that i am missing ? can you explain to me or refer me to something i can read to understand how to use them correctly ?

```
    $userA = $request->getParam('usera');   
    $userB = $request->getParam('userb');
    $userC = $request->getParam('userc');

    $sql = "SELECT *FROM admins";

  try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':Adminusera', $userA);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Adminuserb', $userB);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Adminuserc', $userC);

    $stmt->execute();

    $admin = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $db = null;

    if(!empty($admin)){
    $newUsers = array('a' => $userA, 'b' => $userB, 'c' => $userC);

    print_r($newUsers); }
```

Comment: Normally, php error messages also show the line where the error occurs. Is it really the line where you create the array?

Comment: @mixable not really showing a line, i'm using postman, when i remove the bindparam section the array shows empty values

Comment: Can you post the whole code something is missing and by showing us a part we cannot figure it out

Comment: to be honest that is the whole code, i am new to bind param can it not be used without 
   `$db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();`

Comment: and the `$sql` ? Man edit your post add your whole function .

Comment: that is exactly what i am asking, i am not using the params in my $sql, how can i place the variables posted into my array, i'm going to add the $sql to my code, but that is not my question

Comment: @mirvatJ You just deleted your question "_return multiple response data in one response_". I worked some time on it and the solution is finished. Do you still need it?

Comment: @aendeerei yes undeleted the question, sry about that

Comment: @mirvatJ No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I thought you had problem with the binding.....
This is how you can get parameters

```
// $_GET parameters
$request->query->get('name');

// $_POST parameters
$request->request->get('name');
```

I am letting this so if anyone has a problem related to this can find something useful

**[With bindParam] Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.**

So, for example:

```
$name = 'Alex';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE name = :name');
$s->bindParam(':name', $name); // use bindParam to bind the variable
$name = 'Mike';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE name = 'Mike'
```

or

```
$name = 'Alex';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE name = :name ');
$s->bindValue(':name ', $name ); // use bindValue to bind the variable's value
$name = 'Mike';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE name = 'Alex'
```

Comment: thank you for you explanation, but what i need to know is when someone posting to my function can't i catch the values they are sending in their post using getparam and allocate them in the array ?

Comment: thank you buddy, just one last question whats the difference between `$request->request->get('name');` and `$request->getParam('name'); `

Comment: `$request->request->get('name');`
Let you  fetch POST data from request

`$request->getParam('name');`

 Should be some methods from your framework.